# Simultaneous push ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, xcode5

I have a "strange" issue with xcode5 and the new sdk.
I have a Navigation controller.
The root view controller has 2 buttons, both buttons are linked to an action that push a viewcontroller into navigation-controller's stack.
If I run this project on XCode5 and if I push both buttons simultaneous the navigation controller going "crazy" with the message: "nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar".

But if I try the same code with xCode4 the application work also if I push simultaneous.
Have I forgot something??
Is this a already known behaviour?
There are a way to fix this issue?
Thanks a lot

This is the simple sample code
'
    -(void)viewDidLoad
  {
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
UIButton *BTN1= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[BTN1 addTarget:self action:@selector(ACTION) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[BTN1 setTitle:@"XXX" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[BTN1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 100, 100)];


UIButton *BTN2= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[BTN2 addTarget:self action:@selector(ACTION) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[BTN2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 100, 100)];
[BTN2 setTitle:@"XXX" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:BTN1];
[self.view addSubview:BTN2];

}



-(void)ACTION
{
FirstViewController *fi = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:fi animated:YES];


}`
```

Comment: try with initwithNibName for FirstViewController

Comment: mmm it's not this the problem for sure

Comment: What do you want to happen if you push both buttons at the same time?  You can push one view controller or the other, but what would it even mean to push two "at the same time"?

Comment: in xcode4 only one VC is pushed.

Comment: The same problem occurs if i try to push at the same time a button for pushing vc and the back button

Comment: mmmm maybe i've solved with a little (dirty imo) hack

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you are after, but it seems that what you are looking for is something like [BTN1 setExclusiveTouch:YES]; and [BTN2 setExclusiveTouch:YES]; which would simply prevent both buttons from firing simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you... This is the solution :) But I still can not understand why with xcode4 iOS6 and there was no need to do so

Comment: I had the same situation going on in my app. It is pretty hard to find out why the navigation stack gets corrupted. I can't seem to find anything wrong with my code. But this seems to help a lot (and thus made it into an answer for future uses).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent the navigation stack from being corrupted when pressing 2 buttons simultaneously, it is best to set exclusive touch to the buttons you are working with. This way you can prevent multiple triggers of the button action and prevent multiple ViewControllers from being pushed to the stack and corruption to happen.

```
[yourButton setExclusiveTouch:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **button.exclusiveTouch = YES**; on each of your buttons.
You will need to hook them up to UIButtons and set the property in viewDidLoad for example.